# Sphinx and variable phrase searching.

Tags: php, database, full-text-search, sphinx

I'll preface this with everything is working but I thought I'd ask if there is a better way to do this.

I'm using sphinx to do key phrase searches.  Basically i have a database that is full of phrases.  For example.

north korea
north korea nuke test
cbs news

I'm searching that database with a phrase, for example.

North Korea Nuke test just a "first response" aimed at US CBS News

That phrase is being handed to sphinx as a variable so there is really no chance to add boolean operators for an extended search.

That leave me using SPH_MATCH_ANY as my match mode just to be able to get results.

Is there a way I could be doing this more effectivly? I was hoping that sphinx would be able to pick out phrases ( like north korea ) and not just return me hits on words.

Thanks much.
Bruce

Comment: It's not very clear: you want to get "north korea" in hits instead of north and korea? And why?